# Call_back is not working in nats subscribe in python nats.aio.client

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, coroutine, nats.io

I'm trying simple publish subscribe with nats.aio.client module  but callback is not working below is my code
from nats.aio.client import Client as NATS

class NAT:
def **init**(self):
self.nc = NATS()

```
async def run(self):
    # nc = NATS()
    print("connection starts")
    await self.nc.connect("demo.nats.io:4222", connect_timeout=10, verbose=True)
    print("connection success")

async def publish_msg(self):
    # nc = NATS()
    print("msg to publish")
    await self.nc.publish("Hello", b'Hellowelcome')

async def subscribe_msg(self):
    async def message_handler(msg):
        print("Hello")
        subject = msg.subject
        reply = msg.reply
        print("Received a message on '{subject} {reply}'".format(
            subject=subject, reply=reply))

    await self.nc.subscribe("Hello", cb=message_handler)
```

main file

```
import asyncio
from nats_client import NAT

nat = NAT()
nats_connection = asyncio.get_event_loop()
nats_connection.run_until_complete(nat.run())
nats_connection.run_until_complete(nat.subscribe_msg())
nats_connection.run_until_complete(nat.publish_msg())
#nats_connection.close()
```

Let me know if I'm missing anything any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your program might be exiting too early so can neither publish nor receive the message, here is a full example on how to start a service in NATS:

```py
import asyncio
from nats.aio.client import Client as NATS

async def run(loop):
    nc = NATS()

    async def disconnected_cb():
        print("Got disconnected...")

    async def reconnected_cb():
        print("Got reconnected...")

    await nc.connect("127.0.0.1",
                     reconnected_cb=reconnected_cb,
                     disconnected_cb=disconnected_cb,
                     max_reconnect_attempts=-1,
                     loop=loop)

    async def help_request(msg):
        subject = msg.subject
        reply = msg.reply
        data = msg.data.decode()
        print("Received a message on '{subject} {reply}': {data}".format(
            subject=subject, reply=reply, data=data))
        await nc.publish(reply, b'I can help')

    # Use queue named 'workers' for distributing requests
    # among subscribers.
    await nc.subscribe("help", "workers", help_request)

    print("Listening for requests on 'help' subject...")
    for i in range(1, 1000000):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        try:
            response = await nc.request("help", b'hi')
            print(response)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error:", e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run(loop))
    loop.run_forever()
    loop.close()
```

Comment: wallyqs thanks . As you said program got exited too early. So able to fix that issue